# Dojo dojo.event.topic.publish

Tags: javascript

When I am calling the dojo.event.topic.publish to reload the text field in my web application, sometimes it's not reloading.When I analyzed the request in the controller, the form values, and parameters which are passed set to Null value.Its working fine randomly.When I try next time it's working.

I am calling this publish from the onblur of one text field

```
<sx:div id="getSecondEndDateDiv" href="swapReload.action" listenTopics="getSecondEndDateListener" 
    formId="swapDealEntryForm" preload="false" executeScripts="true">
        <s:textfield id="secondFirstEndDate" name="secondFirstEndDateString"
            maxlength="15" onblur="setInProcess();secondFirstEndDateOnChanges(this);notInProcess();" tbIdx="rq"
        attribute="rq" />
            <s:if test ="dispatch eq null || dispatch eq 'amend' || dispatch eq ''" >
    <img src="icon/cal.gif" alt="" border="0" height="16"
                                        width="16" onclick="openCalendar(1,1,'secondFirstEndDate','<s:property value="#session.entityAppDate"/>')" tabindex="-1">
                </s:if>
</sx:div>
```

Comment: Intermittent issues or blurry defined problems are hard to track. Can you provide [smallest example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with repeatable issue so that it proves your effort to solve it and allows anyone from the community to recreate it?

Comment: Thanks Andy.Example when i publish more than one topic from the single text field on blur action , either one function refresh the other field correctly.Some times 2 fields are refreshed properly. <s:textfield id="secondFirstEndDate" name="secondFirstEndDateString"
            maxlength="15" onblur="fun1();fun2()" tbIdx="rq"
        attribute="rq" />  function fun1(){ dojo.event.topic.publish('target1') } function fun2(){ dojo.event.topic.publish('target2')}

Comment: I was referring to example described under linked document. It says about exectutable example that manifests issue you are trying to solve. That helps anyone from community to see problem and try to fix, otherwise people come and go as they see too many questions to ask to understand what exactly is your issue.

Comment: Obviously you neither bother to do any homework nor reply to comments. So let me ask you not to waste time of SO community with such questions, please.

Comment: Sorry Andy for the late reply i will come up with example and document as what you suggested .Thanks

Comment: Hi Andy the issue has been resolved .RootCause:The content length of the request is exceeded the limit and parameters are cleared in the request when we try to publish mutiple times.Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear. Bare in mind though that based on data you provided in question no one would figure it out but you :)

Comment: Here after i will come up with more detail as you told.Thanks for your comments